# Maximum number of avoid areas exceeds limit using avoid areas

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get a route between two points using avoid areas with Routing API HERE maps and I am having the error "Maximum number of avoid areas exceeds limit".

Below you could find the request I am using:
https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=#####&app_code=#####g&waypoint0=geo!39.4640023,-0.3850572&waypoint1=geo!39.476885,-0.3801068&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&avoidareas=39.45315053433366,-0.3745426849935516;39.45244111598196,-0.3758222574575006!39.45646192309658,-0.3727107307399733;39.456087897102364,-0.3738696063317133!39.45594467628818,-0.37061955378352013;39.455610302758494,-0.37146705481229625!39.46063897809171,-0.3637087111174383;39.460208373008,-0.36463342201032306!39.46027406507121,-0.3644229889377801;39.45945896807123,-0.36512131930616654!39.45778290983732,-0.36235345142498465;39.45722411730335,-0.36284132909356276!39.458055076124936,-0.3685070306751628;39.45796969111227,-0.369566281083658!39.45960790790132,-0.36670532495457014;39.45880954421065,-0.3687782227883713!39.46786419209955,-0.3788290555558871;39.466598324440575,-0.37952348064968555!39.46629280916266,-0.37952060299424345;39.46579450682472,-0.3798614186868332!39.447906189702366,-0.3865406097869585;39.44771727050539,-0.38799155376945255!39.447906266440604,-0.3860336486039068;39.44767149909636,-0.3866130855790714!39.45518409583871,-0.3836551666444044;39.454907307568014,-0.38405749286187724!39.45964221683283,-0.38704088462136754;39.45899783260966,-0.38824034688297143!39.46042754674725,-0.3884778363064053;39.45992759234617,-0.3890550711354175!39.46052328505597,-0.38689531313812037;39.459738005168106,-0.38822226990415315!39.46193614040639,-0.389429648171608;39.46154553298938,-0.3900677999760695!39.46191503182935,-0.39018276482275266;39.46111159154079,-0.3909970310465749!39.4639823644881,-0.39148296845987174;39.46280010046198,-0.39256505432368666!39.467739617727254,-0.38146113326699044;39.46706936907706,-0.3821015492686101!39.46976679855793,-0.3846784165944088;39.46901057325898,-0.3860335643592155!39.469205752460745,-0.38845565289929074;39.46871087077631,-0.38937325235434783!39.47401789680908,-0.39616459840290014;39.4733842284781,-0.396270815957154!39.47423647867104,-0.39540645561031434;39.47401789680908,-0.39616459840

I would like to know if this limitation is because I am using a free trial plan or because the API have this limitation. In this case any idea to solve this limitation?

Below you could find the here guide to use Avoid areas, if someone is interested.
https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/example-route-avoiding-an-area.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is an API limitation. Trial credentials don't limit the functionality of available service.

Comment: Hello Artem. Thank you very much for the answer.