# Avoid limited number of avoid areas in Routing API

Tags: here-api

i have the case that the i exceed the maximum limit of avoid areas by using avoid areas in Routing API.
There is a similar Question here:
[Maximum number of avoid areas exceeds limit using avoid areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089402/maximum-number-of-avoid-areas-exceeds-limit-using-avoid-areas)

But i am not able to aks further questions. The answer says that it is an API-Limit.

But my question is, if there is an possilibity to avoid this limit?

Thanks,
RAS

Comment: for a particular user there will be a limit upto some extent if you are using a freemium account, In your case if you what to extend the usage of your limited usage go with pro. Otherwise you have to switch between users which would be useless!!

Comment: Do you have any idea what the limit is for premium users? Is it documented anywhere? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation this is what you can pass in the parameter and there is **No** other way to avoid this limit as this is there for various reasons like performance and functional reasons.

> Note: You need to specify multiple avoid areas and use the "!"
>   character as a separator. You can specify up to 20 areas to avoid.